# How to get XML data from assets in android?

Tags: android, android-xml

I have stored an XML file in assets folder, and I want to retrieve data XML file which I stored in assets in android, give me a solution.

```
<Response>
    <RequestID>1001</RequestID>
    <FunctionStatus></FunctionStatus>   
    <Message></Message>

<Result>    
    <Banner>

    <Banner_List>
        <Banner_id>3794</Banner_id>
        <Banner_url>http://www.metromatinee.com/agile_dogs/05.jpg</Banner_url>
        <Movie_name>Rose Guitarinaal</Movie_name>
        <gender>Movie</gender>
    </Banner_List> 
</Response>
```

I tried
 `InputStream is = getAssets().open("demo.xml");` 
but exception caused 
any help..???

```
03-27 11:03:04.939: E/AndroidRuntime(432): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 11:03:04.939: E/AndroidRuntime(432): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-27 11:03:04.939: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getAssets(ContextWrapper.java:74)
03-27 11:03:04.939: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at com.service.example.DemoBussinessExecutePage.executeBussinessFunction(DemoBussinessExecutePage.java:230)
03-27 11:03:04.939: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at com.service.example.Service_Manager.executeBussinessFunction(Service_Manager.java:38)
03-27 11:03:04.939: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at com.service.example.Service_class$1.onClick(Service_class.java:57)
03-27 11:03:04.939: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
03-27 11:03:04.939: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
03-27 11:03:04.939: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-27 11:03:04.939: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-27 11:03:04.939: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-27 11:03:04.939: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-27 11:03:04.939: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 11:03:04.939: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-27 11:03:04.939: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-27 11:03:04.939: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-27 11:03:04.939: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And atlast i got the solution for it.

```
AssetManager am = Class.getAssets();
        try 
        {
            InputStream is = am.open("1001.xml");
            int length = is.available();
            byte[] data = new byte[length];
            is.read(data);
            demoInput = new String(data).toString();
        }
        catch (IOException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

```
  InputSource is = new InputSource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.config));
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc=db.parse(new InputSource(is.getByteStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
  NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("woeid");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
        {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
            fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("countrywoeid").item(0).getTextContent();
            fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("countryname").item(0).getTextContent();
        }
```

Here is the XML inside the raw folder of the project

```
 <settings>
 <title>Configuration</title>
 <Version>1.0</Version>
 <Gadgets>6</Gadgets>
 <woeid>
  <countrywoeid>2211096</countrywoeid>
  <countryname>Asia/Karachi</countryname>
 </woeid>
 <woeid>
  <countrywoeid>2211177</countrywoeid>
  <countryname>Asia/Karachi</countryname>
 </woeid>
```